# Clarification regarding undetermined coefficient rule

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There is a rule in my book that states: If the particular solution contains terms that duplicate in $y_c$, multiply the particular solution with the lowest power of x such that no duplication remains.

So let's say I have a complementary solution
$y_c = c_1x $ and a particular solution
$y_p = Ax^2+Bx+C $.
Now I know that I will multiply the B term in the particular solution by x since it duplicates in the complementary solution. My question is that do I also multiply the A term and C term in the particular solution by x even though they don't have a duplicate in the complementary?

Comment: It says, "multiply the particular solution...." You write "a particular solution [is] $y_p=Ax^2+Bx+C$. Doesn't that answer your question?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give the differential equation under consideration. From the available data it could be in the simplest case $y''=x^2$.

Comment: @Lutz, how is $y_p=Ax^2+Bx+C$ a solution of $y''=x^2$? And how would giving the differential equation help?

Comment: The concrete ODE would confirm that the method is applicable at all to your task. One could suspect that you have $xy'-y=x^2$ where the homogeneous solution is indeed $c_1x$ but the coefficients are non-constant. // $Ax^2+Bx+C$ is the first ingredient to the solution, after that you notice the double resonance and complete it to $y_p=x^2(Ax^2+Bx+C)$. In the given equation you could of course also just integrate twice to find $y_p=\frac1{12}x^4$.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is that if the term on the right side that you are currently considering is in resonance with the linear differential operator, then you have to multiply with a monomial. More precisely, if the term is $$p(x)e^{rx}$$ and $r$ is a characteristic root of multiplicity $m$ of the left side, then the corresponding term in the particular solution $y_p$ is of the form $$x^mq(x)e^{rx}$$ where $q$ has the same degree as $p$ with as of yet undetermined coefficients.

---

In conclusion, for your concrete problem it means that you have to multiply the whole expression, to get $$x(Ax^2+Bx+C).$$

Comment: If I multiply the whole particular solution by x then the C term becomes $xC$. Now the C term duplicates the complementary solution, Would I need to multiply the entire particular solution by x again them?

Comment: You are right, if $1$ and $x$ are basis solutions, then the multiplicity of $r=0$ is $m=2$ and thus you need to multiply with $x^2$.